# Android : how to set the initial date on the datepicker

Tags: android

I'm working on a basic app for a class project with a calorie counter and I want the user to be able to set his own goal date for achieving his goal weight.`

```
mDisplayGoalDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH );
            day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                    RegII.this,
                    android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
                    mDateSetListener,
                    year,month,day);
            dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() + ExtraMilliCalTime);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.show();
        }
    });

    mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
            month = month + 1;
            Log.d(TAG, "onDateSet: mm/dd/yyy: " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year);

            String date = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
            mDisplayGoalDate.setText(date);
        }};`
```

I used the above code to get a date picker for the user to select their goaldate, only when I run the app when they select the textview it doesnt open the picker. The logcat only leaves:

> 02-28 21:52:48.420 3000-3238/? I/InputReader: Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=] when=7002662331000
>   02-28 21:52:48.420 3000-3237/? I/InputDispatcher: Delivering touch to (25430): action: 0x1, toolType: 1

I'm not sure but I'm guessing it's because I made the datepicker have an initial date of the current date but a minDate adjusted by how many calories they have to lose/gain so the mindate is ahead of the current date. How do I change the initial date the datepicker starts with? Or, if that's not the problem, what is?

Comment: What is the purpose of the ExtraMilliCalTime variable? I've tested your code without this variable and the datepicker is showing. Are you  using a textview or a edittext?

Comment: It's a TextView. yeah it works without it, but the variable is basically the minimum amount of days a person can go from their current weight to their desired weight in milliseconds, I was trying to set the minimum date they could chose to reach their goal weight as the current time + this variable but i think because i'm using Calander.getInstance it sets the initial date as the current date which is before the minDate. Atleast that's the only problem i can see.

Comment: How are you setting the ExtraMilliCalTime value? It's a long variable? I've done this ExtraMilliCalTime = 5184000000L; //(60 days) and it's work for me.

Comment: ExtraMilliCalTime = (long) Math.abs(((((DesiredWeight - weight) * 7700) / 400) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));  (7700 being calories in a kilo, 400 being max calories you can lose or gain in day, the rest to convert days into milliseconds)

Comment: Strange...it's working for me. It must be something out there. Do you set focusable or clickable to false on your textview?

Comment: Nope. I tried do it with 5184000000L and it didnt work can you send me your code?

Comment: I messed around with it and it doesn't work even when i set the minDate before the currentDate i think i did something wrong that is making it not open. Any ideas?

Comment: I paste my code here https://pastebin.com/Fh5UZD7k. Take a look at it.